# how to get the store in a component in ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, nullreferenceexception

How in the world do i get a handle on the store inside of a component? I'm trying to create an auto-complete component that returns results from the store.

```
App.AutoCompleteComponent = Ember.Component.extend({

    //-------------------------------------------
    // Ember Properites
    //-------------------------------------------
    content: Ember.ArrayController.create(),

    //-------------------------------------------
    // Instance Properties
    //-------------------------------------------
    queryText: "",

    componentItemSelected: null,

    //-------------------------------------------
    // Observers
    //-------------------------------------------
    queryTextChanged: function () {
        this.updateContent(this.get("queryText"));
    }.observes("queryText"),

    //-------------------------------------------
    // Instance Methods
    //-------------------------------------------
    selectItem: function (item) {
        this.set("componentItemSelected", item);
    },

    updateContent: function (queryText) {

        if (queryText.length <= 5) {

            console.log('not greater than 5 chars');
            return;
        }

        this.get("content").setObjects([]);

        var items = App.Company.find();

        this.get("content").setObjects(items);
    }
});
```

here is my company model

```
App.Company = DS.Model.extend({

  name: DS.attr('string'),

  created_at: DS.attr('date'),

  updated_at: DS.attr('date'),

  people: DS.hasMany('person')

});
```

I've tried:

- `this.get('store')`
- `DS.Store.find('company')`
- just `store`
- `App.Company.find()`

I always get an `Uncaught TypeError ... has no method 'find'`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The real answer is you shouldn't.  A component should be agnostic of the outside world, and adding a dependency on the store breaks that concept.  Really you should get the models beforehand (in the route, or controller, depending on the logic) and passing them into the component.

https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md

> In general, looking up models directly in a component is an anti-pattern, and you should prefer to pass in any model you need in the template that included the component.

Now that I've said that, just pass the store into the component.  It lives on the routes and controllers, so when you create a component send in the store as one of the arguments, then you can access it using `this.get('store')`

```
{{auto-complete store=controller.store}}
```

or

```
{{auto-complete store=store}}
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/720/edit

Comment: That transition document is definitely what i need. thank you thank you!

Comment: So components can't create records? Or do server-side validation on them?

Comment: They can, whether or not doing it is a recommended pattern is generally no.

Comment: I had to use this.store in my case.